# probabilistic neural network Error In Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Hello I have biometric data such as record.mat. In record variable P denotes training features and T denotes target data. I am using new newpnn command for classification and I am taking this error:

> Error using network/subsasgn>network_subsasgn (line 551)
>   net.IW{1,1} must be a 212-by-212 matrix.

[Here](https://files.fm/u/v77666cc) is my  dataset and here are codes.

```
clear all
load record.mat ;
P = record.P;
Tc = record.T; 
T = ind2vec(Tc) 
net = newpnn(P,T);
Y = sim(net,P);
Yc = vec2ind(Y);
```

How can I overcome this problem? Thanks

Comment: I think you should check the PNN [architecture](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/probabilistic-neural-networks.html) I think this may help you to find right matrix dimension

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error related to input matrix dimensions and data type.

```
clear 
load record.mat;
P = double(record.P)'; %add ' and convert single to double will solve the issue
Tc = record.T; 
T = ind2vec(Tc); 
net = newpnn(P,T);
Y = sim(net,P);
Yc = vec2ind(Y);
```

I hope this help

Comment: since it works for you, please accept my answer. [see how?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)